# AmCharts Stock Graph

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am wondering which object that colour settings for the 'red' balloon and line are under for the AmCharts Stock Chart. See picture below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ChartCursorSettings.cursorColor and ChartCursorSettings.categoryBalloonColor